# How can I make validation behave properly?

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix, asp.net and razor. I have been following [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2).

This page must insert values into a database, it does it prefectly at first but then when I add validation, it gives me this error "Exception Details: System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32." The database used is all nvarchar except for Techid that is an int. But what I don't understand is when I comment out

```
Validation.Add("no", Validator.Range(9,10 ,"Contact number can not be longer or shorter than 10 digits"));
Validation.Add("num", Validator.Range(13,13,"Is number must be 13 digits"));
Validation.Add("name", Validator.Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$", "Invalid format for a name"))
```

it works quite fine.

```
@{  
    var db = Database.Open("ProjectTest");
    var Name = Request.Form["name"];
    var Surname = Request.Form["surname"];
    var IDNumber = Request.Form["num"];
    var Address = Request.Form["add"];
    var ContactNumber = Request.Form["no"];
    var Course = Request.Form["course"];
    var TechID = Request.Form["techID"];
    var grade = Request.Form["grade"];

    Validation.RequireField("name", "Name is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("surname", "Surname is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("num", "num is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("add", "add is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("no", "no is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("course", "course is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("grade", "grade is needed");

    Validation.Add("no", Validator.Range(9,10 ,"Contact number can not be longer or shoter than 10 digits"));
    Validation.Add("num", Validator.Range(13,13,"Is number must be 13 digits"));
    Validation.Add("name", Validator.Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$", "Invalid format for a name"));  

    if (IsPost)
    {
        if (Validation.IsValid())
        {
            var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (Name, Surname, IdNum, Address, ContNum, Course, Grade) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3 ,@4, @5, @6)";
            db.Execute( insertQuery, Name, Surname, IDNumber, Address, ContactNumber, Course, grade );
        }
    }      
    else
    {
          ModelState.AddFormError("There are some errors with your submission"); 
    }  
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/Home">Home</a><br>
              If you are an Student that wants to register use this form.<br>
       <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td><td><input type="text" name="surname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>ID Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="num"><br></td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="add"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="no"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Course:</td><td><input type="text" name="course" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Grade:</td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("name")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("surname")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("num")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("add")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("no")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("course")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("grade")
       </form>  
       <select name="courses">
           <option value="1" id="test">S7</option>
           <option value="2">Commerce</option>
       </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Validator.Range` will validate if a numeric value is between minimum and maximum. Looks like you want to validate the length of the input, so you should use `Validator.StringLength()`.

Comment: Since I'm here can you tell me exactly what language I am using? I know it sounds dumb, but two people I know dont know this language.

Comment: I am not sure it this is what you mean, but the programming language you are using on this code is C#.

Comment: I see...So this is not ASP.NET?

Comment: It is ASP.NET... but the language you are using is C# (you could be using VB too). This is a ASP.NET web page using C# as the language.

Comment: what probably is confounding the people you mentioned is that your site is using "asp.net web pages"  (as opposed to "asp.net webforms" or "asp.net mvc"). "Web Pages" is a simplified type of web project that comes with webMatrix. With Visual Studio, you get only webforms and mvc. Yo can read about the 3 types of projects here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp